# Multiple objects triangulation in 3D, intersecting the right vectors (rays)

Tags: math, 3d, computer-vision, linear-algebra, triangulation

I am working on a project in which I should be able to triangulate the position of multiple objects when they are seen by (at least) two cameras.

## Single object

Currently I am able to triangulate a single object. This is done in some steps:

1. For every camera, it is calculated the vector pointing to the pixel where object's center lies. This is done by properly rotating the vector pointing at the center of the image (0,0,1) on Y and X axis.
2. Then every direction vector is converted from camera's own coordinates to world coordinates (through glm math library) in order to have a common coordinate system to perform calculus.
3. Endpoints of the [minimum length segment](http://geomalgorithms.com/a07-_distance.html) between each couple of rays are computed. A ray here is defined as *position of the camera + λ * direction vector with λ >= 0*.
4. The average of segments' central points is the approximate object's position in the world.

## Multiple objects

My problem with multiple objects is that I can't find a proper way to determine if a pair of rays are pointing the same object, so they should be matched, or not.

[image: example of intersections]

I think I am close to a solutions but I am still missing the last piece. My partial solution is empirical and works with the various angles involved, in particular I use the following four angles:

- **α**: angle between directions of the rays
- **β1, β2**: angle between camera's direction and own ray's direction (x2)
- **δ**: angle between the directions of the cameras

[image: angles involved]

The relation I found is

```
α + β1 + β2 - δ = 0
```

I made some tests and sometimes it works, sometimes it would if changing the sign of β1 and/or β2. The problem is that I don't know how to determine when. I have an **additional information** to use, the (x,y) angles used in step 2 to produce the direction of the ray from (0,0,1).

These two values are signed and **strictly related** to βn, because (0,0,1) is basically the direction of the camera in camera's own coordinate system and the same is true for the computed ray direction. So I think they will determine the sign of β, but I don't know how.

Any idea on how to finish it? Is this model mathematically correct?

Comment: Why not choose the assignment that minimizes the minimum length segments?

Comment: There are some drawbacks with it. Measurements are not accurate, I can imagine a case where two rays pointing the same object are not linked by the shortest segment. Also it would be difficult to determine the number of objects seen. I feel that the approach with the angles (if mathematically correct) would be much more robust. I could then use the length of the segments for a double check.

Comment: Yes, one can imagine an indeterminate case, but in three dimensions with a small number of objects, such cases are rare. Your angle relation is correct (if one keeps track of signs), the problem is that it works for the real objects *and also for the illusory ones marked in red.* If the minimum length segments aren't good enough, isn't there some other property of objects that you can use? Radiance? Color? Motion?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the relation is true even with illusory objects. I'm afraid that without the depth of the pixels there is not a lot I can do. Maybe you are right, such cases are unlikely to happen, I'll try using only the minimum segment and see what happens. There are other info like motion, but I prefer to use the final position later to match newly detected object against old ones and not mix things up.

Comment: sorry if i'm missing something obvious, but I don't see how you can decide, from the cameras pixel locations alone, when you are in a situation with the objects like in the 'OK' case or with the actual objects in the red crosses in the 'BAD' case. Both situations will produce exactly the same positions in the camera. So unless you add some extra information, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: It is what I was trying to figure out, but yes it seems impossible to do that with certainty. I need stereo vision for that, with a depth map I could cut off rays into finite segments, then the minimum length between them would be a much more accurate indicator. But unfortunately I don't have such setup. Anyway, maybe something can be done.